# Enterprise App distribution for Windows Phone 8 - Does it require sideload licenses?

Tags: windows-phone-8

So I'm a little confused. We are developing a Windows Phone 8 application but want to sideload it and bypass the store (it's for internal use). I've read all the documentation (at least I think all of it) that requires us to have an AET, Enterprise store, etc. But I'm a little confused on the Sideload Licenses.

Do I need to buy this (J7S-00005) license in order to sideload WP8 apps to devices? Or can I just get the certificate, put it on my secure site and download/install?

Thanks.

Comment: I know there is something called "Company App" but don't know if it is exactly what you are trying to find.

Comment: Hey @VitorCanova that is correct. That's one of the options I've read. I've discovered a little more in that the sideload licences are only for RT and Desktop applications. It seems that Mobile and Tablet are excused. I'll test and find out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options:

- [Company app distribution for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [Targeted app distribution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj619160%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (these are "hidden" in the store, but anyone that stumbles across the link can install it)
- Developer unlock and sideload on each phone

Coming in Windows Phone 8.1, from May 2014, It [is reported](http://microsoft-news.com/you-can-buy-windows-8-1-enterprise-sideloading-rights-for-an-unlimited-number-of-devices-for-100/) that Windows Phone 8.1 devices (and 8.0 devices once updated) will be able to sideload apps in the same way that Windows Store apps can be on the desktop/tablets. To quote the relevant section:

> [Microsoft will] grant Enterprise Sideloading rights to organizations in certain Volume License programs, regardless of what product they purchase, at no additional cost.
>
> Other customers who want to deploy custom line-of-business Windows 8.1 apps can purchase Enterprise Sideloading rights for an unlimited number of devices through Volume Licensing at approximately $100.

Comment: Ok, so my thinking and info I've find is correct. I've read the same articles and looks like the first bullet point (company app) is the way to go. I'm in the process of getting the Symantec cert so I can generate the AET, etc. I'm wondering if I can host it on my website similar to how you can do iOS app distribution.

Comment: @Valien just added additional info coming "soon" which way help in your decision making...